# How to access a base class property from instance of child class C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, parent-child

I have the following code:

```
public Abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseProperty {get; set;} 
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass 
{
    public int ChildProperty {get; set;}
}

public class test 
{
    public test()
    {
        ChildObject = new ChildClass ();
    }

    public ChildClass ChildObject  {get; set;}
}
```

In class `test` I want to access the property `BaseProperty` of the base class, `ChildObject.BaseProperty` doesn't work and if I did

```
int num = (ChildObject as BaseClass).BaseProperty ;
```

a conversion error occurs.

Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean b.P1 does not work?

Comment: [`var t = new test(); Console.WriteLine(t.b.P1);`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QyUIwU) should work just fine... Not sure what is your real issue with it or if you even understand your the classes you mixed.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, `b.P1` does work as well as `(b as A).P1`. btw: why is `A` `abstract` if no `abstract` members are declared?

Comment: Is it possible that you have just made some spelling (case) errors? Confusing `b` with `B` and `p1` with `P1`?

Comment: Conversion error ? Are you sure you pasted the exact same classes here ? There should not be a conversion error if `B : A`

Comment: In the OP I think it really is just case sensitivity - `p1` vs `P1`. [Here's the DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vGVIfW). My long winded explanation was probably irrelevant.

Comment: @ScottHannen How would `p1` instead of `P1` cause a conversion error ? Unless the OP thought it was one.

Comment: Sorry Guys I actually on my original code didnt use abstract this why I was getting other behavior that I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Just use `b.P1`. (Here's a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vGVIfW) for convenience because I'm all about convenience.)

Think of it like this: `B` inherits from `A`. So even though `P1` is technically a property of `A`, `B` also has that property because it inherits from `A`. You can always treat an instance of `B` as if it's an instance of `A`.

Side note - I've noticed that both the questions and answers are a little easier to read if we avoid using names like `A`, `B`, `BaseClass`, `InheritedClass`, etc.

So here's the same explanation using some more verbose examples. "Car" is seriously overused, but I'm going to use it anyway.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int NumberOfDoors {get;set;}
}

public class Truck : Vehicle
{
    public int NumberOfCountryMusicianEndorsements {get;set;}
}
```

If you create a new instance of `Truck`

```
var truck = new Truck();
```

You can cast it as a `Vehicle`

```
var vehicle = (truck);
var numberOfDoors = vehicle.NumberOfDoors;
```

But you don't need to because `vehicle` is already a `Vehicle` because `Truck` inherits from `Vehicle`. So `Truck` has the same properties as `Vehicle` plus its own.

```
var numberOfDoors = truck.NumberOfDoors;
```

There's even a fancy term for this - it's called the Liskov Substitution Principle. In brief, it means that if `Truck` inherits from `Vehicle` then you should be always be able to use a `Truck` as a `Vehicle`. You can always substitute an inherited class for any one of its base classes. (That's not always true. Sometimes you can't. That means someone did something wrong. The principle means that you *should* always be able to.)

Comment: `B.1` is not C#, `B.P1` won't compile since `P1` is not static.

Comment: @RenéVogt he did say a instance of B.

Comment: @Prix I was talking about the first line "Just use `B.1`".

Comment: @RenéVogt and I was talking about the latter part of your comment.

Comment: @Prix and that latter part referred to the possibility that the first line was meant as "Just use `B.P1`" which would still be wrong.

Comment: @RenéVogt not really considering he was talking about an instance(giving his message) of and that P1 was right, var b = new B(); b.P1 is jut fine. But Its up to you how you interpret it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant B.P1.

Comment: for the sake of naming conventions the it should not be a capital B but b.

Comment: That's why I recommend using more verbose names for examples. The case sensitive issue aside, it's definitely harder to read.

Comment: Sorry again, meant b.P1, not B.P1. Curses. Some details don't matter. That one did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have  a variable spelling error , in A you define `P1` using upper case  and in B you define `p2` using lower case , be consistent in naming and accessing `b.p1` will work